# wrong number of arguments (3 for 5..7)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, syntax, arguments

I worked off of a tutorial and it seems the syntax for my new.html.erb is outdated.  I am not certain for sure but here is my code:

```
    <h1>Add new skill</h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
<p><label for="skill_title">Title</label>:
<%= text_field 'skill', 'title' %></p>
<%= collection_select(:skill,:id, :title) %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<%= end_form_tag %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

my error is this:

```
    ArgumentError in Skills#new
Showing app/views/skills/new.html.erb where line #5 raised:

wrong number of arguments (3 for 5..7)
```

and it is pointing to this line specifically as the problem:

```
 <%= collection_select(:skill,:id, :title) %></p>
```

I will keep researching and hopefully will find my answer.  Thank you anyone who takes a look, cheers! and good luck!

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537450/what-does-wrong-number-of-arguments-1-for-0-mean-in-ruby)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [Can someone explain collection_select to me in clear, simple terms?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8907867/2413778)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, I am not the same person if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`collection_select` requires an identifier as the first argument and in the provided example the variable form is not set. Therefore the code should read:

```
<%= collection_select :skill, :id, Skill.all, :id, :name %>
```

Try this i don't know your model attributes so map your code to look like this.

And also see:

[Collection_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select)