# Passing parameters via URL to Controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, controller, parameter-passing

Having an issue here in Rails where I have already made some of my routes for passing parameters in the URL.

```rb
#routes.rb
root 'day#show'
get '/day/:date/:activity' => 'day#show'
get '/day/:date' => 'day#index'
```

The Day controller I made is as follows

```rb
#day_controller.rb
class DayController < ApplicationController
  def show
    if(!params.has_key?(:date))
      @date = getCurrentDate()
    else
      @date = splitDate(params(:date))
    end
    @days = Day.where("year = ? AND month = ? AND date = ?",@date[0],@date[1],@date[2])
    if(params.has_key?(:type))
      @activity = getAllData(params(:type))
    end
  end

  def index
    @date = params(:date)
    if(@date[0] == "?")
      @days = Day.all
    elseif(@date[1] == "?")
      @days = Day.where("year = ?",@date[0])
    elseif(@date[2] == "?")
      @days = Day.where("year = ? AND month = ?",@date[0],@date[1])    
    end
  end

  private

  def getCurrentDate
      date = DateTime.now.to_s
      dateArrayOne = date.split('T')
      dateArrayTwo = dateArrayOne[0].split('-')
  end

  def splitDate(date)
      finaldate = date.split('-')
  end

  def getAllData(type)
      dataHash = {}
      case type
      when "calories"
        @days.each do |day|
            dataHash[:day.date] = day.calories
        end
      when "steps"
        @days.each do |day|
            dataHash[:day.date] = day.steps
        end
      when "activeMinutes"
        @days.each do |day|
            dataHash[:day.date] = day.activeMinutes
        end
      when "distance"
        @days.each do |day|
            dataHash[:day.date] = day.distance
        end
      else
        @days.each do |day|
            dataHash[:day.date] = day.calories
            dataHash[:day.date] = day.steps
            dataHash[:day.date] = day.activeMinutes
            dataHash[:day.date] = day.distance
        end
      end
      dataHash
  end
end
```

So whenever I input any URL with the date or activity parameters (the root is fine, as it just gets the current date), I get the error:

> ArgumentError in DayController#index: wrong number of arguments (1 for
>   0) at app/controllers/day_controller.rb:15:in 'index'

The parameters are getting passed, as indicated within the exception page where it lists:
`Request Parameters: {"date"=>"2015-03-01"}`

So through all of this I have a couple of questions...

1. Am I setting routes right?
2. Am I accessing the params correctly in my controller?

Please give me any feedback, I am quite new to Rails and would enjoy learning how I could improve on my structure. Also sorry for the messy code, I haven't had much time to refactor or comment much.

Comment: Are you using strong parameters? have you permitted date?

Comment: Next time, plz highlight which line of the posted code block you mean. The error is within `params(:date)`. It should be `params[:date]`. No neccessary need for strong parameters here, as you're not using mass assignment to ActiveRecord and you're also prorcessing the date parameter manually

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)" mean in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537450/what-does-wrong-number-of-arguments-1-for-0-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 4):

You should use `params[:date]` instead of `params(:date)`. It acts like a hash, not like a function.

Patrick's solution is almost correct, but is misleading because he is not using strong parameters correctly. Strong parameters are required for POST data, but not for URL parameters in GET requests.

If it were an action that handles POST data, with json input formatted like this:

`{ "day": { "date": [2015, 3, 15], "activity": "running" } }`

then you would use strong params. `params.require(:day)` would give access to the inner hash, and so `params.require(:day).permit(:date, :activity)` would give access to the values. You would use it like this:

```
def index
  if day_params[:date] //not params[:date], which would raise an error
    @date = day_params[:date]
    if(@date[0] == "?")
      @days = Day.all
    elseif(@date[1] == "?")
      @days = Day.where("year = ?",@date[0])
    elseif(@date[2] == "?")
      @days = Day.where("year = ? AND month = ?",@date[0],@date[1])    
    end
  end
end


private
  def day_params
    params.require(:day).permit(:date, :activity)
  end
```

As a completely separate issue, `dataHash[:day.date]` will not work. That would call the `date` method on the symbol `:day`, which does not exist. You probably want to use `dataHash[:day].date`.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Rails 4 you will need [strong parameters](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html):

```
private
  def day_params
    params.require(:day).permit(:date)
  end
```

Then you can do something like:

```
def index
  if params[:date]
    @date = params[:date]
    if(@date[0] == "?")
      @days = Day.all
    elseif(@date[1] == "?")
      @days = Day.where("year = ?",@date[0])
    elseif(@date[2] == "?")
      @days = Day.where("year = ? AND month = ?",@date[0],@date[1])    
    end
  end
end
```

P.s. I'm not sure if it how you copy and pasted but please consider using [proper indentation convention](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide).

Comment: defining and not using day_params; not the reason for the error; see also comment above